# When using a square wave inverter is arcing a problem when installing a switch

Tags: switches, inverter, arcing

A perfect square wave switches immediately from a high positive voltage to a high negative voltage. Does this mean that a switch installed in a circuit powered by a square wave power inverter will have the same arcing problems as a switch installed in a DC circuit?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.